# Is this code safe for Auto Refreshing Tabs?

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML= `<iframe id="testFrame" src=""+window.location.toString()+"" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%;"> </iframe>`; setInterval(()=>{document.getElementById("testFrame").src=document.getElementById("testFrame").src},10000)
```

This script was obtained here: https://www.technipages.com/how-to-auto-refresh-chrome-tabs-without-an-extension

I wanted to paste it into my browser's dev tools console, but it gave a general warning about doing this, saying that pasting stuff into the dev tools console that you don't know what it does may be unsafe.

The goal of this script is to automatically refresh the page that the browser tab is on every 10 seconds. There is a link provided to the article that explains this in the link name as well as within the article itself.

All I am looking for is an expert with HTML & Java Script to take a quick look to see if there is anything malicious in this code. From what I can tell, it looks pretty safe. It does not seem to be opening a back door, listening on ports, or sending any data.

Comment: What do you want to achieve

Comment: Without the warning, it's gonna be hard for us to explain what they mean...

Comment: Inside a template literal you don't use `+` to concatenate expressions, you use `${expression}`. And you don't need to call `.toString()`, that's done automatically.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. You're putting the current document in an iframe. This will cause infinite regress, since that will execute the same code that creates another nested iframe, and so on.

Comment: You have too many quotes around the `src=` attribute.

Comment: Please read the guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The page you linked to used this code in a bookmarklet (prefixed with `javascript:`) or the developer console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken with a person who works in Java Scripting designing websites since posting this and they seem to think that this code is safe.  They understand the commands and claim that it is not harmful at all.  And yes, it works for what it was designed to do.

Comment: Please mark as an answer.